# Why can't I free an pointer "array" of structs that each have pointers inside?

Tags: c

Let's say we have this code which reads in 10 space separated strings in a file and prints them all out.
When running the code, I get a "heap-use-after-free" error.
First, I tried removing LINE A. Doing so gave me a "attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed" error.
Next, I tried removing LINE B and re-adding LINE A. Doing so gave me a "detected memory leaks" error.
I feel like I'm in a bit of a bind here. How do I properly free everything? (both the "pointer array" of structs and the character "pointer arrays" inside of each struct)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct strs {
    char* s;
} str;

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc + 1]) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    //Malloc
    str* ex = (str*)malloc(10 * sizeof(str));
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        (ex+a)->s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    }

    //Scan
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s ", (ex+a)->s);
    }

    //Print
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        printf("%s ", (ex+a)->s);
    }

    //Free
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        free((ex+a)->s); //LINE A
        free(ex+a); //LINE B
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The number of calls to `free` should be equal to the number of calls to `malloc`, and what is passed to `free` should be exactly the same as what was returned from `malloc`.

```
str* ex = (str*)malloc(10 * sizeof(str));
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    (ex+a)->s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
}
```

Here you call `malloc` once for the array of `str`, then 10 more times for the `s` member in each array member.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    free((ex+a)->s); //LINE A
    free(ex+a); //LINE B
}
```

The first line inside of the loop is fine.  The second one is not because `ex+a` was not a value returned from `malloc` (except for the first iteration).

You need to free the `s` members inside of the loop, then you free the array after the loop.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    free((ex+a)->s);
}
free(ex);
```